# Google Cloud Storage : Python API get blob information with wildcard

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get blob information from a bucket but i want to use wildcards in blob name. Consider my bucket

```
$ gsutil ls gs://myBucket/myPath/
gs://myBucket/myPath/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-11/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-12/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-13/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-14/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-15/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2019-02-18/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2019-02-19/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2019-02-20/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2019-02-21/
```

now from the command line, i am able to do

```
$ gsutil ls gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018*
gs://myBucket/myPath/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-11/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-12/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-13/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-14/
gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018-12-15/
```

and hence i can do the same for the size

```
$ gsutil du -sh gs://myBucket/myPath/ranOn=2018*
2.7 G
```

now, i want to do the same thing with the python api. Here is what i tried

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('myBucket')
blob = bucket.get_blob('myPath/ranOn=2018*')
print('Size: {} bytes'.format(blob.size))
Size: None bytes
```

why is this not working? How can i use wildcards in blob paths with python api?

Comment: gsutil implements wildcards in its code added above Cloud Storage. This is not a feature supported by the Cloud Storage API. You will need to do the same in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `get_blob` is just for getting individual files, not multiple files.

You'll need to iterate over all the files that match the prefix and sum their sizes to get the total size.

```py
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix="myPath/ranOn=2018")

total = sum([blob.size for blob in blobs])
```